# How do I pin my organization branch location on a map with no Internet available?

Tags: mapping-engine

I have to pin my organization branch location on a map. I need a map because my server doesn't have an internet facility to get a map from Google or bing.

How can i do this?

Comment: @Ayyappan: I can't see how this is a question about SharePoint so I've closed it. Please use the `flag` option if you disagree. Thank you!

Comment: I am getting the SPEC like this requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot rely on a public mapping service then you would need to license a mapping application you can host internally.  Something like ESRI would make it possible, though this can get very expensive.